# Vuejs dynamic ref undefined

Tags: vuejs2, ref

I have dynamic list of input from an items list :

```
<ul>
  <li v-for="item in items">
    <input type="checkbox"
        :value="item._id"
        :id="item._id"
        :ref="item._id + '-checkbox'"
        @click="checkItem($event)"
    >
    {{ item.libelle }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

As you can see, I want to bind `:ref`, dynamically, with `item._id`
This is OK, `console.log(this.$refs)` gives me `items._id` concatenated as expected :

> 5b116f28f1167507d7fa2004-checkbox  5b116f28f1167507d7fa2005-checkbox
>   5b116f28f1167507d7fa2006-checkbox

When an input is checked, I add into `itemsChecked` array.

Next, in `mounted()` method, I want to loop on items checked array and check input item using their dynamic ref :

```
for (var i = 0; this.itemsChecked.length; i++) {
  var currentRefId = this.itemsChecked[i];      
  if (this.$refs[currentRefId + '-checkbox'] !== 'undefined') {
     this.$refs[currentRefId + '-checkbox'].checked = true;
  }
}
```

I get an erreor:

> vue.runtime.esm.js:1689 TypeError: Cannot set property 'checked' of
>   undefined

Seeing other related topic about use dynamic ref in vuejs, I dont understand why it's not working in my example.

In another fixed ref, it's working fine:

```
this.$refs.mychecbox.checked = false
```

Comment: `undefined` shouldn't be quoted.

Comment: if I remove quote, it's crash my app. how to test without quote ?

Comment: Why do you insist to using `refs`? this can handle without it.

Comment: In addition `  ... !== 'undefined' `  is different from `... !== undefined`.

Comment: @Chris if `itemsChecked` is an array of items, then `var currentRefId` contains an item not a `_id`. So you should do `this.$refs[currentRefId._id + '-checkbox']` to find the ref.

Comment: This is *definitely* an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Why do you bind the `_id` as the checkbox value. This example seems weird.

Answer (score 0):

When accessing `$refs` created loops like this, I found that the required item is the first item in sub-array. Do it like this:

```
(this.$refs[currentRefId + '-checkbox'])[0].checked = true;
```

See an actual working example of this in my [replayer app](https://github.com/suterma/replayer-pwa/blob/main/src/components/Compilation.vue#L121) source code.